# PHP Yii Framework using private fields in a model

Tags: php, html, model-view-controller, web, yii

I have following model:

```
class OsobyFormularz extends CActiveRecord
{
    // Deklaracja zmiennych tabeli osoby (nazwy takie jak atrybutów w tabeli osoby)
    public $id;
    public $imie;
    public $nazwisko;

    // Metoda model dziedziczy wszystkie właściwości klasy nadrzędnej zwracając parent::model
    public static function model($classname = __CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($classname);
    }

    // Zwraca nazwę tabeli w bazie danych
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'osoby';
    }

    // Zwraca tablicę atrybutów - klucze to nazwy pól w tabeli osoby
    // wartości natomiast to polskie odpowiedniki które ustawiliśmy
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'imie' => 'Imię',
            'nazwisko' => 'Nazwisko'
        );
    }

    // Ustanawia zasady walidacji danych
    // W tym przypadku imie i nazwisko nie mogą być puste
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('imie', 'required'),
            array('nazwisko', 'required')
        );
    }


}
```

And here is view:

```
<div class="form" style="padding: 15px">

    <!-- Wczytanie wtyczki (o nazwie CActiveForm) drugi parametr - opcje wtyczki (ustawienie
    identyfikatora id formularza na osoby-formularz oraz wyłączenie walidacji przez Ajax) -->
    <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'osoby-formularz',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => false
    ));
    ?>

    <p class="note">Pola oznaczone <span class="required">*</span> są wymagane.</p>

    <?php
    // Jeśli zmienna zapisano == true, to wyświetl komunikat oraz dane nowo zapisanej osoby
    if ($zapisano == true)
    {
        echo '<div style="color: #600000">Dane zostały zapisane.</div>
        <br>';
        echo '<p>Dane nowo dodanej osoby:</p>';
        echo 'Imię: '.$model->imie.'
        <br>';
        echo '<p>Nazwisko: '.$model->nazwisko;
    }
    ?>
    <!-- Wyświetla informacje o błędach walidacji formularza -->
    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <!-- Div będący polem formularza - imieniem -->
    <div class="row">
        <?php
        // Tworzy nam label Imię. Jako parametry przekazujemy model oraz nazwę pola w bazie danych
        echo $form->labelEx($model, 'imie');
        // Wyczyszczenie pola imie w formularzu
        $model->imie = "";
        // Jak wyżej, tylko tworzy pole do wprowadzenia tekstu (imienia)
        echo $form->textField($model, 'imie');
        // Wyświetla informacje o błędzie dla danego elementu formularza (w tym przypadku dla imienia)
        echo $form->error($model, 'imie');
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php
        echo $form->labelEx($model, 'nazwisko');
        $model->nazwisko = "";
        echo $form->textField($model, 'nazwisko');
        echo $form->error($model, 'nazwisko');
        ?>
    </div>


    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Dodaj'); ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Zamyka wtyczkę -->
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

    </div>
```

Now what I want to do is to have $id, $imie and $nazwisko private, not public. But then how can I connect a view with a model in a controller? At the moment my controller looks as follows:

```
class FormularzController extends CController
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        // Inicjalizacja modelu
        $modelOsoby = new OsobyFormularz;
        $zapisano = false;

        // Sprawdzenie, czy za pomocą metody post została wysłana zmienna formularz.
        // Wszystkie formularze tworzone na podstawie modelu zawierają ukryte pole
        // o nazwie takiej samej jak nazwa modelu
        if (isset($_POST['OsobyFormularz']))
        {
            // Przesłanie danych z formularza do modelu
            $modelOsoby->attributes = $_POST['OsobyFormularz'];


            // Jeśli walidacja danych się powiodła - zapisz i ustaw $zapisano na true
            if ($modelOsoby->validate())
            {
                $modelOsoby->save();

                $zapisano = true;
            }
        }

        // Wczytuje formularz oraz przekazuje do niego model i info o wykonaniu akcji ($zapisano).
        $this->render('formularz',
            array(
            'model' => $modelOsoby,
                'zapisano' => $zapisano
        ));

    }
}
```

Comment: You should add a public `getImie()` and `getId()` method to your model, so you can access their values from the view while still making the actual properties private.

Comment: I tried that, but with no success. I don't know where to put these methods. I also created a setters.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CActiveRecord::getAttribute()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#getAttribute-detail) method to read field value. And [CActiveRecord::setAttribute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#setAttribute-detail) to set value.

```
echo $model->getAttribute('imie');
$model->setAttribute('imie', 'value');
```

Comment: As I said I tried doing that with getters and setters and no success. I need something more, I tried searching but everywhere they declare public fields.

Comment: How can I get that value from the textfield so I can put it in the model?

Comment: I just tried that and setAttribute doesn't work :/ I try to get the value from textfield using $_POST

Comment: For example, you may use `CModel::setAttributes(array)`.

Comment: What is in `print_r($_POST)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112445/discussion-between-mnv-and-mindroller).